# Android WebView: can't make a fullscreen div element

Tags: android, html, web, webview

I want to have a div that has exactly the same size as the screen (or viewport) so the code:

```
<html>
  <body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;background:blue">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background:red"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simple. It shows a red screen in my desktop chrome browser. Same with the android mobile chrome. But with a WebView in my app, it shows a blue screen. I've tried 50% height and it works well as intended in both of desktop and mobile chrome browser, but not for WebView. The div always has height of 0. Red rectangle is shown only when I set the height of div in an absolute unit like 100px. How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I found out what was wrong. Basically android webview and chrome for android share the same rendering engine. [This doc](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) says:

> New Webviews also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.

So if some code works for one, it is supposed to work for the other. If it doesn't, probably there's something wrong with the settings on the webview. [API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says:

> It is recommended to set the WebView layout height to a fixed value or to MATCH_PARENT instead of using WRAP_CONTENT. When using MATCH_PARENT for the height none of the WebView's parents should use a WRAP_CONTENT layout height since that could result in incorrect sizing of the views.

My webview layout:height used to be set to WRAP_CONTENT and after I changed it to MATCH_PARENT, it worked just as chrome for android.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve with javascript.
Do you know javascript code ?

```
<html>
  <body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;background:blue">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%;background:red"></div>
  </body>
</html>
        <script>
            var val  = window.screen.height;
                document.getElementById("myDiv").height = val;
        </script>
```

And one last thing is javascript enabled in webview client.

Comment: This works, but it's kinda hacky and my question was why the same code works with mobile Chrome but not with webview which uses the same rendering engine. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @K J Which webview client you use ?

Comment: android system webview 52.0.2743.98

Comment: you can use chrome webview client and check it again.